# How to show a form using Yii2 framwork?

Tags: php, forms, yii2, apache2, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a simple form using yii2 framework.

[image]

This code is in backend/controller/PostController.php :

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;
use Yii;
use backend\models\PostForm;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
    public function actionNew()
    {
        $model = new PostForm;
        if($model -> load( Yii::$app -> request->post() ) && $model -> validate())
        {
            return $this -> render ('_show' , ['model' , $model]);
        }else
        {
           return $this->render('_form' , ['model'=>$model]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This one is in backend/models/PostForm.php :

```
<?php
namespace backend\models; 
use yii\base\Model;
class PostForm extends Model
{
public $title;
public $content;
public $date_add;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title','content','date_add'], 'required '],
        ['date_add' , 'integer']
    ];
}
}
?>
```

and this is in backend/views/post/_form.php:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<? $form -> field($model , 'title') ; ?>
<? $form -> field($model , 'content') ; ?>
<? $form -> field($model , 'date_add') ; ?>
<? Html::submitButton('submit'); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

but when I type backend.projectname.loc/post/new in my browser the page is shown like this image:

uupload.ir/files/e6xf_screenshot_from_2017-02-08_19:32:15.png

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply try echoing your field.  USe  `<?= or <?php echo`

```
<?php
   use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
   use yii\helpers\Html;

 ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form -> field($model , 'title') ; ?>
<?= $form -> field($model , 'content') ; ?>
<?= $form -> field($model , 'date_add') ; ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('submit'); ?>
<? php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

you are using html helper for submit button so at the top of you view you should add

Comment: i got this error!        Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class required does not exist'

Comment: but html helper is exist @scaisEdge

Comment: so what is the class  required  that not exist ? .. show  all the error  message

Comment: try commenting your  rules row with required  in your models/PostForms  ... seems tha you have some problems in model  too

Comment: More specifically, you have [['title','content','date_add'], 'required '].  Remove the trailing space from 'required '.

Comment: @sonofagun   you we see very well ,... that't the problem .. good

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of errors

```
<? $form -> field(.....) ?>
```

• First of nothing... this code must be started with:

```
$form -> field(...) ;
```

Must be:

```
$form->field(...);
```

Tell me if that solves your problems, greetings.

Sorry for my bad english xD

Edit, you can replace your actionNew, now use this:

```
public function actionNew()
    {
        $model = new PostForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            return $this->render('_show', ['model', $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

The same for _form.php

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;

?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'title'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'content'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_add'); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('submit'); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: you mean i must use this 3 lines?
    $form->field($model,'title') ;
    $form->field($model,'content') ;
    $form->field($model,'date_add') ;

Comment: i'm watching a tutorial video and i just wrote only what the video says!

Comment: i got this error! Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class required does not exist'